# Calling a custom function in slave kernel process connected through mathlink

Tags: programming, packages, mathlink-or-wstp, kernel

I am performing a small experiment to check if we can call/execute a custom package function in slave kernel launched from master using mathLink.

I have created a dummy application called "DummyMathLink" and put the application in AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Applications path which is included by default in $Path. This application contains a package which have "dummyPlus" as one of the public function.

I am able to execute the functions "dummyPlus" in slave kernel as below:

```
(*This is my main kernel/master*)
In[1]:= Needs["DummyMathLink`"]

In[2]:= link = LinkLaunch[First@$CommandLine <> " -wstp"]

Out[2]= LinkObject["WolframKernel -wstp", 94, 4]

In[5]:= LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[Module[{},
    local = dummyPlus[12, 43];
    local + 3
    ]
   ]]

In[6]:= While[LinkReadyQ[link] == True, Print[LinkRead[link]]]


(*Output*)
During evaluation of In[6]:= InputNamePacket[In[1]:= ]

During evaluation of In[6]:= ReturnPacket[58]
```

everything works as expected till now.

I thought of extending this one step further i.e to try if dummyPlus works in slave kernel(k3) launched by other slave kernel(k2) which is launched by master kernel(or my main kernel/notebook).
This is the code i came up with to achieve the result:

```
(*This is my main kernel/master*)
In[1]:= Needs["DummyMathLink`"]

In[2]:= link = LinkLaunch[First@$CommandLine <> " -wstp"]

Out[2]= LinkObject["WolframKernel -wstp", 94, 4]

In[3]:= LinkWrite[link, 
  Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[
  Module[{link}, 
    link = LinkLaunch[First@$CommandLine <> " -wstp"];
    (*Send data to be evaluated on Kernel k3*)
    LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[dummyPlus[13, 444]]];
    Pause[2];
    (*Read the result of slave kernel k3*)
    While[LinkReadyQ[link] == True, Print[LinkRead[link]]]
  ]
 ]
]

In[4] := While[LinkReadyQ[link] == True, Print[LinkRead[link]]]

 (*Output*)
 TextPacket[InputNamePacket[In[1]:= ]
 ]
 TextPacket[ReturnPacket[dummyPlus[13, 444]]
 ]
 ReturnPacket[Null]
```

> This shows the dummyPlus function is not evaluated in kernel k3, Any idea how to make this function accessible to kernel k3?,

I have tried writing "Needs[DummyMathLinks`]" to the link between k2 and k3, but it gives me some shadowing related error as below:

```
TextPacket[TextPacket[

>    dummyPlus::shdw: 
    Symbol dummyPlus appears in multiple contexts {DummyMathLink`, Global`}
     ; definitions in context DummyMathLink`
      may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions.
>    ]
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.